# Update to the latest version of zurb-foundation using foundation-cli

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I created a foundation site using foundation-cli. Now, I need to update the zurb-foundation SASS files, javascript, and other related files to the latest version of zurb-foundation.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `foundation update` but we do not user Bower anymore. Not sure if the CLI can update the latest releases.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/blob/master/readme.md